# Sum the series to 'n'

Tags: python, series

Just trying to sum the series `1/(1 + 3n)` for a given `n`.  I've used the code below and get an `"invalid syntax"` message, but I can't understand why as other examples seem to do the same. Returning a value rounded to two decimal places

```
def series_sum(n):
    ans = 0
    for i in range(0, n+1):
        ans = ans + (1/(1+3i))
    return round(ans, 2)
```

Comment: Did you get a line number with that error? Also, is the indentation here **exactly** as in your own code?

Comment: `1+3i` is invalid syntax. Whitespace matters in programming (unlike math). Use `(1 + 3 * i)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just do :

```
def series_sum(n):
    ans = 0
    for i in range(0, n+1):
        ans = ans + (1.0/(1.0+3.0*i))
    return round(ans, 2)
```

you should use `*` for multiplication and have float in your equation to get your result as float.

Also the indentation is really important in python.

Comment: no explanation what was changed and why?

Comment: In Python 3 at least, adding in the floats is unnecessary. Since a single slash means non truncating division.

Comment: apologies. the indentions were done correctly and everything mirrors the above solution.  the multiplication sign was needed, but it is not evaluating correctly.  when n=2 i get 1.00 instead of 1.25

Answer (score 1):

Here is an identation corrected version of your code showing the error

```
$ cat d.py 
def series_sum(n):
    ans = 0
    for i in range(0, n+1):
        ans = ans + (1/(1+3i))
    return round(ans, 2)

$ pyflakes d.py
d.py:4:28: invalid syntax
        ans = ans + (1/(1+3i))
                           ^
```

And here is how to fix it

```
def series_sum(n):
    ans = 0
    for i in range(0, n+1):
        ans = ans + (1/(1+3*i))
    return round(ans, 2)
```

Writing "3i" is not valid syntax for "3 times i" so use the `*` operator to multiply

```
$ python
Python 3.5.3 (default, Jun 22 2017, 11:09:36) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-17)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from d import series_sum
>>> series_sum(2)
1.39
```